# Certain Texts breaks in Edge and Chrome - Browser compatibility

Tags: kendo-ui, cross-browser, kendo-grid, microsoft-edge

I have a kendo grid where certain texts break and goes into next line when checked in Chrome or Microsoft Edge. But in Internet Explorer 10, the texts doesnt break. Please refer below images for better understanding.

Chrome View:

[image]

Internet Explorer View:

[image]

Here is the code that I have used to display the column. How can I fix the text breakage issue across all browsers without increasing the width.

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Code).Width(4100).Title("A/C Code").Filterable(false);
```

Comment: Which version of Edge are you using? You can use F12 dev tools **Elements** tab to check the CSS styles applied on the element. You can provide the related CSS styles on that element in IE and Edge so that we can compare the differences between them and see how to change the styles to make them look the same in different browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a ClientTemplate to put the value in with some css to prevent the wrap. Like so:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Code)
       .Width(4100)
       .Title("A/C Code")
       .Filterable(false)
       .ClientTemplate("<span style='white-space:nowrap;'>#=Code#</span>");
```

I'm not a CSS guru - you maybe could use white-space:pre as well